# form.__EVENTTARGET.value undeffined in js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

at my webforms.app on .net 4.0 after call _doPostBack via

aspx code

```
<%= GetPostBackReference() %>;
```

on code behind

```
protected string GetPostBackReference()
{
    return Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ReloadThePanel,"null");
}
```

transformed to

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$cntMain$ReloadThePanel','null');
```

in form

```
<!-- update panel -->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelSave" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReloadThePanel" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<!-- hidden button for update panel -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="ReloadThePanel" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
```

after first ajax postback is all ok, after another one ajax postback on same page it throw js exception

form.__EVENTTARGET.value undeffined

in (Scriptresource.axd ... dynamic code)

_doPostBack: function PageRequestManager$_doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) ....

```
form.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
form.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
this._onFormSubmit();
```

what i do wrong ? Its maybee same isue with http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx
problém is only on ie 11,8 usw.. Chrome and FF works well
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is upgrade to 4.5.1 - it may be that issue you mention and that'd solve it.

Seems strange that it happens AFTER and initial postback though (and doesn't tie in with the issue above).

Personally I don't see much point in creating the postback reference by using a hidden button (and suspect that's where it's getting itself confused). You have blank content template here, but there is probably something contained within in the real code, make sure you don't have any unmatched div tags as that would push the button into the panel and you'd lose reference to it.

I'm guessing that you must be calling the postback from javascript (otherwise why use a hidden button), so why not just use:  . You might want to populate the id programatically (in aspx : ', '');"> )

I know it seems nasty including direct references to __dopostback - but the day M$ change that is the day that 90% of webforms websites will go down anyway, so it's pretty unlikely.